# CSS pulsating button effect with pseudo-elements

Tags: css, css-transitions, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I am confused with these button animation codes. These codes produce a pulsating effect button, but I am having difficult time interpret how they work together or what is under the hood.

```
<div >   
    <a href="#" class="btn btn--white btn--animated">btn</a>
</div>
```

style.css:

```
    .btn:link,    
    .btn:visited {    
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 10rem;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 6rem;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 1.5rem 4rem;
      transition: all 1.2s;

    }

    .btn:hover {
      transform: translateY(-.3rem);
      box-shadow: 0 1rem 2rem  rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    }


    .btn:active {
      transform: translateY(-.1rem);
      box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem  rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    }


    .btn--white {

      background-color: #fff;
      color: #777;
    }


    .btn--white::after {    
      background-color: #fff;
    }


    .btn::after {    
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 10rem;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      transition: all .2s;    
    }


    .btn:hover::after {    
      transform: scaleX(1.4) scaleY(1.6);
      opacity: 0;


    }
```

My main confusions are:

-- How do I read ::before/after use plain English, with `.btn::after`? Can I read it as: after running .btn code, run these code here?  or with  `.btn--white::after { background-color: #fff;}` I can read: after .btn--white executed, paint background white?

-- with `.btn::after` we created empty btn box right behind the original link button, when we use `.btn:hover::after` isn't the mouse pointer suppose to hover on the original button link instead of the empty button because of Z-index?

-- How does pulsating effect was rendered here? how does the `.btn--white::after` get called for constantly repainting the empty button?

Comment: Answer to your first question, `after creates a pseudo-element that is the last child of the selected element` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after

Comment: Answer to your second question: the .btn:hover:after means that when you hover over the buton, the after element takes some new properties that you might add. it does not matter what the z-index is.

Comment: Third question: In this situation the only thing that the .btn-white::after has is a background color, that does not do anything because it already is white. In the html the btn class is already styled in the desired way. if you put more classes in html, the next class's styling is overwriting the previous one.

Comment: Last one: in the first part of the css, the button has it's styling done. When you hover the button the box-shadow and transform traslate-Y effect take place. The btn:after here as well as btn--white:after and btn:hover:after are just default bootstrap, you can remove them and still get the same effect.

Comment: You can play around with them, change their colors and background colors, try different animations and see exactly where the differences are.